# How to create datetimepicker dynamically with same id? not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetimepicker

I am having hard time to figure out how to create datetimepicker dynamically. 
I am using The code below for creating datetimepicker on a cell in datatable dynamically. when I click on a cell, datetimepicker created on it dynamically. and I click other cell, datetimepicker disappears and create another on the clicked cell.

The way I am trying is that when the event occurs I use append function with id. see below sample code.

```
<div id='textId'></div>


//when eventA occurs,
{
    $('#testId').empty();
    $('#testId').append('2019-09-01');
}
//when eventB occurs,
{
    $('#testId').empty();
    $('#testId').append(<input type="text" class="form-control"/>'
                +'<span class="input-group-addon"><span class="fa fa-calendar"></span></span>');
    $('#testId').datetimepicker({format: 'YYYY-MM-DD', date : '2019-09-02'});
}
```

The code for eventA works fine. But the problem is eventB. when eventB occurs first time, it works fine. From the second time, datetimepicker does not work at all. It displays its form but does not have date and not work the calendar-call-buttn.

I googled the problem and found that it was about using same-id issue. So I tried to use name attribute but failed with the same result.

helps me...

Comment: which `datetimepicker` are you using?

Comment: @NidhinJoseph the datetimepicker is 'eonasdan-bootstrap-datetimepicker'

Comment: instead of id use class. two html items should not have same id

Comment: @SangitaKendre I tried it with class but the result was the same...

Comment: Share more details about eventA and eventB . Is is ajax call or some onclick event. Share code if possible

Answer (score 0):

please you can try to using css class for datetimepicker.

```
<div class="col-sm-3 form-group">
    <b>Date Of Birth :*</b><br>
    <p><input placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy" class="form-control calanderDate" oninput="this.className = ''" name="dateOfBirth" id="dateOfBorth" onblur="defaultValidation(this)"></p>
    <span id="er_passportNumber" style="display: block; width:100%; float: left;"></span>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    defaultDateValidation();
});

function defaultDateValidation(){
     $(".calenderDate").datetimepicker({ 
         dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy"
    }); 
}
</script>
```